# Skip CRM Record While Retreiving from CRM Using OrganizationServiceProxy

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am fetching record from CRM using OrganizationServiceProxy and i want to skip some records from the beginning. scenario is that for instance I have 2 Entities Called A and B.  I am using RetrieveMultiple method of OrganizationServiceProxy.

A has 27 records

B has 32 records

Total = 59

and I have 1 method that fetches records from both, first priority is Entity A and then Entity B. now suppose page size = 10

**in first call,**
10 records from Entity A is return

**in 2nd call,**
another 10 records from Entity A

**in 3rd call,**
7 records from Entity A and 3 records from Entity B

**in 4th call,**
10 record from Entity B **(but I want to skip first 3 and starts from 4th record because it's already fetch during 3rd call)**

so I want to skip records while fetching data from CRM. I have search a lot but didn't get any thing. I method is that if i fetch all records from CRM and do pagination from LINQ.

Comment: Wait, you are managed to do an union of 2 RetrieveMultiple resultsets (entity A + B) to get merged dataset inside your method. But Paging cookies are for pagination on RetreiveMultiple call itself.. so you have to pagination in local merged dataset using LINQ..

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to be using Paging Cookies. See link for example and more info.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328046.aspx

**Edit**

You need to recreate the paging cookie for each iteration of your loop, but base it on the existing paging cookie.

The code below is from the example I linked to.

```
    public string CreateXml(string xml, string cookie, int page, int count)
    {
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);

        // Load document
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);

        return CreateXml(doc, cookie, page, count);
    }
```

This first method takes your FetchXml, pagingcookie, current page and number of items to return per page. It in turn calls the following:

```
    public string CreateXml(XmlDocument doc, string cookie, int page, int count)
    {
        XmlAttributeCollection attrs = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes;

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            XmlAttribute pagingAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("paging-cookie");
            pagingAttr.Value = cookie;
            attrs.Append(pagingAttr);
        }

        XmlAttribute pageAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("page");
        pageAttr.Value = System.Convert.ToString(page);
        attrs.Append(pageAttr);

        XmlAttribute countAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("count");
        countAttr.Value = System.Convert.ToString(count);
        attrs.Append(countAttr);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);

        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        doc.WriteTo(writer);
        writer.Close();

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This builds up your new FetchXml to return the next page of results, but uses the current paging cookie to determine which is the next page that needs to be returned.

Then it's simply a matter of calling the following to get your results;

```
RetrieveMultipleRequest fetchRequest1 = new RetrieveMultipleRequest
{
     Query = new FetchExpression(xml)
};

EntityCollection returnCollection = ((RetrieveMultipleResponse)_service.Execute(fetchRequest1)).EntityCollection;
```

Read through the complete code sample in the link and make sure you understand what it is doing. It's all there.

Comment: from page cookie i able to get Unique Identifier of last element..but how can I fetch records after last record?